# Why after calling pandas.read_json memory usage increase more than the size of dataframe?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I was curious about where my code uses a lot of memory so I logged it out and found that read_json uses a lot of memory. From the code and the output, you can see that before read_json my Python process used 258MB of memory and after read_json and garbage collected it used 920MB, but the DataFrame only used 297MB of memory.

Here is my code.

```
logging.info(f"before read_json: {process.memory_info().rss}")
df = pd.read_json(
    "tmp/json/cleaning.json", orient="table"
)
logging.info(f"after read_json: {process.memory_info().rss}")
gc.collect()
logging.info(f"after garbage collect: {process.memory_info().rss}")
logging.info(f"dataframe: {df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()}")
```

output:

```
before read_json: 258744320
after read_json: 928083968
after garbage collect: 920219648
dataframe: 297222977
```

920MB - 258MB - 297MB = 365MB

Where does the extra 365MB come from? (df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() should include all the metadata already)